# in Grafana how to pass a search query to search two strings with OR operator in logs?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

```
{app="overflow"}|="Checking error 1" OR |="Checking warning 1" OR |="Checking info 1"
```

I tried this one it was not working.
Please let me know what can be tried to have two strings searched up in one query.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following query:

```
{app="overflow"} |~ "(Checking error 1)|(Checking warning 1)|(Checking info 1)"
```

Obs: if you have problems, try one of the following options:

```
{app="overflow"} |~ `(Checking error 1)|(Checking warning 1)|(Checking info 1)`
```

or

```
{app="overflow"} |~ "Checking error 1|Checking warning 1|Checking info 1"
```

Comment: got the query error its saying that it has unexpected identifier. I think the brackets which has the string it should not be like that, its some text we are searching. So may be something different, may work. But yes, the problem is to search two strings in one query.

Comment: I just added other alternative formats.